# Double tangent bundle of manifolds, two contradictory arguments

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, supermanifolds

I am considering the double tangent bundle $T(TM)$ of manifolds $M$. Locally, if $M=R^d$ then $T(TM)=R^{4d}=\oplus^3 TM$. My attempt is to see whether $T(TM)\cong \oplus^3 TM$ naturally for any $M$. I have two contradictory arguments, of which one says $T(TM)\not\cong \oplus^3 TM$ but the other seems say $T(TM)\cong \oplus^3 TM$.

1. If we introduce local coordinates $(x^i)$ on $M$, then $(x^i, dx^i)$ can be local coordinates on $TM$, and $(x^i, dx^i, \delta x^i, d\delta x^i)$ can be local coordinates on $T(TM)$. But the rules for change of coordinates is a bit complicated for $T(TM)$, which involve the second derivatives of transition functions of $(x^i)$. So we can not hope $TTM\cong \oplus^3 TM$.
2. From argument above we have three different maps $TM\to TTM$ given by $(x^i, dx^i)\mapsto (x^i, dx^i,0,0)$ or $(x^i, 0,\delta x^i,0)$ or $(x^i,0,0, d\delta x^i)$, thus we have a map $\oplus^3 TM\to TTM$ of vector bundle over $M$. This map is locally an isomorphism, as we saw $T(TR^d)=R^{4d}=\oplus^3 T R^d$, so this is also a globally isomorphism.

To put it in another way. Let $M$ be a manifold and $D=\{x\in R| x^2=0\} $ be the infinitesimal line in synthetic geometry, then $Map(D, M)$ is the tangent bundle, where $Map$ denotes the internal hom. Applying twice we get $Map(D^2, M)$, which is the twiced tangent bundle. The second argument translate to

- $Map(D^2, R)=Map(D, R)\oplus Map(D, R)\oplus Map(D, R)$, so we may replace $R$ by any microlinear superspace, hence $Map(D^2, M)=Map(D, M)\oplus Map(D, M)\oplus Map(D, M)$.

Could you point where did I make mistake(s)? I think the second is wrong, but I can not tell why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Your answer 1. is local and coordinate dependent, thus 2. is not well defined.
For a chart change (a diffeomorphism) $\phi$ the mapping $TT\phi$ looks as follows:
$$
(TT\phi)(x,dx,\delta x,d\delta x) = (\phi(x),\phi'(x)(dx),\phi'(x)(\delta x), \phi''(x)(d x,\delta x) + \phi'(x)(d\delta x)).
$$
Note that the forth component transforms exactly as Christoffel symbols for a linear connection do.

For a description of the second tangent bundle of a manifold see 
8.12 and 8.13 of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf).
For a comprehensive description of higher order order tangent bundles etc, viewed as product preserving functors on the category of smooth manifolds, see
chapter VIII of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf), or [the original paper](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/nat-transf.pdf).
Thsi description uses Weil algebras and is related to what you are trying to say at the end of your question.

Comment: Thanks Prof Michor, now I see the second argument goes wrong: I can define three maps $TM\to TTM$, but these maps are not morphisms of vector bundles ($TTM$ is not a vector bundle over $M$), thus I cannot obtain a welldefined map $\oplus^3 TM\to TTM$. I have tried the synthetic approach, and it also stuck at $M^{D^2}$ is not a vector bundle.

Answer (score 0):

$T(TM)$ is not isomorphic to $\oplus^3 TM$, it is isomorphic to $\oplus^2 TM$. For example, if $M=\mathbb{R}$, then $TM$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $T(TM)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: The expression $\bigoplus^2 TM$ usually means the sum as vector bundles (and that is what is meant above), so it has dimension $3n$ if $n$ is the dimension of $M$. But in fact, even if you mean $TM \times TM$ when you write $\bigoplus^2 TM$, that doesn't work either. The bundle $T(TM)$ retracts down to $M$, while $TM \times TM$ retracts to $M \times M$, so for compact $M$ of postiive dimension, these are not homeomorphic. So I am not sure what you mean here.